# cant select both 2 fields from 2 different tables with the same name

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query='SELECT * FROM #__virtuemart_products as a 
LEFT JOIN #__virtuemart_products_en_gb as b ON a.virtuemart_product_id = b.virtuemart_product_id
INNER JOIN #__virtuemart_product_categories as c ON a.virtuemart_product_id=c.virtuemart_product_id
INNER JOIN #__virtuemart_categories_en_gb as d ON c.virtuemart_category_id = d.virtuemart_category_id 
WHERE b.slug LIKE "'.$current.'%" AND a.product_parent_id = 0
AND d.category_name="'.$query_title.'"' ;
$db->setQuery($query);
$options=$db->loadObjectList();
```

This is the query i use to parse some products from my db. The problem is:
Table: virtuemart_products_en_gb has a collumn named slug
Table: virtuemart_categories_en_gb has also a collumn named slug

When i used $row->slug it parsed the virtuemart_categories_en_gb slug.

So after i var_dumped the ObjectList i see that there is only 1 collumn named slug. After i used the same query in phpmyadmin, it returns me 2 collumns named slug.

I think i could fix that selecting every single record individual and setting first slug as slug1 and second as slug2.
For example: `SELECT id,username,password,b.slug as slug1,c.slug as slug2` etc
Is there any better way ? Cause i need to parse really many fields  and that would make the query really huge.And why the php query returns only 1 field named slug while phpmyadmin returns both of em ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify `*` after selecting the columns with the same name. For example,

```
SELECT *, b.slug as slug1,c.slug as slug2
FROM #__virtuemart_products as a 
LEFT JOIN #__virtuemart_products_en_gb as b ON a.virtuemart_product_id = b.virtuemart_product_id
INNER JOIN #__virtuemart_product_categories as c ON a.virtuemart_product_id=c.virtuemart_product_id
INNER JOIN #__virtuemart_categories_en_gb as d ON c.virtuemart_category_id = d.virtuemart_category_id 
WHERE b.slug LIKE "'.$current.'%" AND a.product_parent_id = 0
AND d.category_name="'.$query_title.'"
```

Comment: `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM uhhu_virtuemart_products as a ` .if i remove the "*" it works fine. Maybe i need to select * first and the define the new var names ?

Comment: after i swapped the query to `"Select *,b.slug as nameslug, c.slug as cat slug` it worked!!! Thanks for the help